Can anyone help me extract whether or not a puppy is "sold" based on the "This puppy is no longer available" message on the list?
I'm trying to build a dataset to extract information from pawrade.com about all of the listed "French Bulldogs".
I've started a scraping script, but I cannot seem to get the "Status" column to work properly.  If you got into the lists of the puppies that have been sold, then you'll see a "This puppy is no longer available." message. I'm using that message to determine whether or not the puppy is sold in the Status column.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# Function to scrape a single page
def scrape_page(url, csv_writer):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    spans = soup.find_all("span", class_="fave position-absolute")
    
    for span in spans:
        adid = span.get("data-adid")
        name = span.get("data-name")
        breed = span.get("data-breed")
        price = span.get("data-price")
        puppy_url = f"https://www.pawrade.com/puppies/french-bulldog/{adid}"

        # Extract additional details from the puppy's individual page
        puppy_response = requests.get(puppy_url)
        puppy_soup = BeautifulSoup(puppy_response.content, "html.parser")

        dob = extract_detail(puppy_soup, "fa-birthday-cake")
        weight = extract_detail(puppy_soup, "fa-weight")
        registration = extract_detail(puppy_soup, "fa-trophy")
        color = extract_detail(puppy_soup, "fa-palette")
        release_date = extract_detail(puppy_soup, "fa-calendar-alt")
        microchip = extract_detail(puppy_soup, "fa-microchip")

        # Determine status based on the presence of specific messages
        status = "available"
        if puppy_soup.find("h4", class_="mb-0") and "This puppy is no longer available." in puppy_soup.find("h4", class_="mb-0").text:
            status = "sold"

        csv_writer.writerow([adid, name, breed, price, puppy_url, dob, weight, registration, color, release_date, microchip, status])

# Helper function to extract details based on class
def extract_detail(soup, class_name):
    detail_element = soup.find("span", class_=class_name)
    if detail_element:
        detail_text = detail_element.find_next_sibling("div").find("small").text.strip()
        return detail_text
    return ""

# URL of the first page of listings
base_url = "https://www.pawrade.com/puppies/french-bulldog/"

# Create a CSV file
with open("french_bulldogs.csv", mode="w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(["AdID", "Name", "Breed", "Price", "URL", "DOB", "Weight", "Registration", "Color", "Release Date", "Microchip", "Status"])

    # Scrape the first page to get the total number of pages
    response = requests.get(base_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    # Example logic to determine total pages - this may need adjustment based on actual site structure
    pagination = soup.find("ul", class_="pagination")
    if pagination:
        pages = pagination.find_all("li", class_="page-item")
        total_pages = int(pages[-2].text.strip())  # Adjust the logic to find the total number of pages
    else:
        total_pages = 1  # Default to 1 if no pagination found

    # Iterate through all pages
    for page in range(1, total_pages + 1):
        url = f"{base_url}?page={page}"
        scrape_page(url, csv_writer)

print("Data has been written to french_bulldogs.csv")


I'm going to guess that the problem is because you're using requests, which cannot process javascript.

Nor can any other library that just performs the http requests - as is the case for most BS4 questions on SO that are unable to get some data, you'll need to use something like selenium to puppeteer a browser to process the JavaScript on the page.

what is the issue? the h4.mb-0 element is available in the static html, it should work. There is also this meta tag meta[property="product:availability"] with a content property = 'in stock' or 'out of stock'.

Your code works. Just look at what you are running it for. You simply can't have puppies sold out, because you are only running it for puppies that are available now. You do a query on base_url then find all the selectors span with that classes fave position-absolute then go through the for loop:
spans = soup.find_all("span", class_="fave position-absolute")
for span in spans:
    ...

The problem is that if we look closer, we find that there are exclusively AVAILABLE puppies here:

And you can test your code like this by modifying it a little bit scrape_page function, like this:
def scrape_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    puppy_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    status = "available"
    is_sold_out = puppy_soup.find("h4", class_="mb-0")
    if is_sold_out and "This puppy is no longer available." in is_sold_out.text:
        status = "sold"
    print(status)


scrape_page('https://www.pawrade.com/puppies/australian-shepherd/75daa83431/')  # sold
scrape_page('https://www.pawrade.com/puppies/french-bulldog/69d02849b1/')  # available

Note, I didn't change the logic for finding status just put the selector in a separate variable for readability.
The only block where you can find sold out puppies is this one, and maybe this is the information you wanted:

In that case, replace the beginning of your function with the following:
def scrape_page(url, csv_writer):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    links = soup.find_all("a", class_="d-block")

    for link in links:
        # Extract additional details from the puppy's individual page
        puppy_response = requests.get('https://www.pawrade.com' + link['href'])
        puppy_soup = BeautifulSoup(puppy_response.content, "html.parser")
        ...



Hey, thanks! I ended up resolving this issue. The website posts both available and sold out, but the sold out puppies are listed along the last pages.
My issue was not reaching all of the pages, so I simply increased the page count.
